# Get active form on event

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, selection

I want the user to tap on a form to "select" it, and if he taps a button (after selecting the form) I will be able to get the selected form into a variable.

here is what I mean:

Let's say we 3 forms open: `SpecificFormType Form1`, `SpecificFormType  Form2` and `SpecificFormType  Form3`. user taps on `Form3` then on `Form2`, then clicks the button.

so in `btn_click` I want to do something like this:

```cs
private btn_click
{
 SpecificFormType  SelectedForm = GetSelectedForm();
//SelectedForm = Form2
}
```

Is this possible?

Sorry if Im being unclear!

Comment: well the btn_click will need to be on the form being selected or the selected form will be the one with the button on.. However, you can certainly take the activeform and make note of it.

Comment: @BugFinder yes, the "main" form will be the one selected, and neither of those three I mentioned, so maybe the one selected before? so I can get the one I really want?

Comment: You could have a variable on the main form, that these other forms update when they activate, so that the last one used is always in that variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a static field that you can put in the `SpecificFormType` class:

```
static private SpecificFormType SelectedForm;
```

When the user tap on a form run this instruction on the corresponding event:

```
SelectedForm = this;
```

And when the user click on a button you can use this field:

```
... this.SelectedForm ...
```